# Dynamically fill in an ArrayList with objects

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I have the abstract class Human, which is extendet by other two classes Student and Worker. I`m am trying to fill in two array lists. ArrayList of type Student and ArrayList of type Worker dynamically.

```
public abstract class Human {

private String fName = null;
private String lName = null;

public String getfName() {
    return fName;
}

public Human(String fName, String lName) {
    super();
    this.fName = fName;
    this.lName = lName;
}

public void setfName(String fName) {
    this.fName = fName;
}

public String getlName() {
    return lName;
}

public void setlName(String lName) {
    this.lName = lName;
}
```

}

```
public class Student extends Human {

private String grade = null;

public Student(String fName, String lName, String grade) {
    super(fName, lName);
    this.grade = grade;
}

public String getGrade() {
    return grade;
}

public void setGrade(String grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}
```

}

```
public class Worker extends Human {

private int weekSalary = 0;
private int workHoursPerDay = 0;

public Worker(String fName, String lName, int weekSalary, int workHoursPerDay) {
    super(fName, lName);
    this.weekSalary = weekSalary;
    this.workHoursPerDay = workHoursPerDay;
}

public int getWorkSalary() {
    return weekSalary;
}

public void setWorkSalary(int workSalary) {
    this.weekSalary = workSalary;
}

public int getWorkHoursPerDay() {
    return workHoursPerDay;
}

public void setWorkHoursPerDay(int workHoursPerDay) {
    this.workHoursPerDay = workHoursPerDay;
}

public int moneyPerHour() {
    return weekSalary / (5 * workHoursPerDay);
}
```

}

```
public class Program {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Student> student = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Worker> worker = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

}

Comment: And where is your problem?

Comment: Dynamically? With what data?

Comment: The problem is that i can not understand how to fill in the arraylist or just a simple array of type Worker[] worker dinamically. Because when i make an instance if Worker for example the constructor that i`ve made must be initialized with its parameters but i do not want to hard code them. I`m trying to do somethind like this but with objects.
int arr[] ...
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = input.nextInt();
for (i = 0; i <n; i++) {
arr[i] = input.nextInt();
}

Comment: Do you need to take input from the user?

Comment: I want to fill in the lists with objects for type Student and Worker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just add the students:

```
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>(); // note: students
students.add(new Student("Jens", "Nenov", "A+"));
```

You can do almost exactly the same thing for the workers. If you want to use a loop, do the following:

```
for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
    students.add(new Student("Jens"+i, "Nenov", "A+"));
}
```

This will create a list of new students with different numbers after their names. If you want different data, though, that data needs to come from somewhere. For example, you might get the data from user input:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
for ...
    System.out.println("Enter a first name:");
    String firstname = input.nextLine();
    ...
    students.add(new Student(firstname, lastname, grade));
```

Comment: Yes that is an option but if i want to add 25 students i have to do that 25 times. That`s why i want to do this dinamically with loop. But i do not know how :(

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I could help. Good luck with your program!